# How to create Visual Studio extension (vsix) targeting Visual Studio Community Edition

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vsix, vsixmanifest

I am upgraging and old Visual Studio extension. It's simple, so I want to target all possible versions of Visual Studio. As it [seems](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/explore/explore-vside-vsi.aspx) that Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition now supports extensions:

> With the new Community edition, any developer can use those extensions as well.

I have decided to include it as well.

The problem is that I am not sure how to update the .vsixmanifest file in order to support the Community Edition - this is the `<InstallationTarget>` element's `Id` property, which, according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh696828.aspx), has the following "expected" values:

- Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntegratedShell
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.VWDExpress
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.VPDExpress
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSWinExpress
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSLS
- My.Shell.App

none of which is an obvious choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just target Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro. Also visx with a vspackage is not installable in VS Express editions, no matter what you put in the manifest, in fact only CE or higher will install these.